# How to use Background agent to send toast notification?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

I am working on windows development & I am displaying the items on the emulator by using a web service. 
Now I want to send a toast notification when an item added to the service. Already I worked with push notifications. But It’s generating push channel URL when app is initialized. 
I don’t want to use this channel URL. So I tried Background Agent & Shell Toast to send the notification. Its working fine for static data. How can I add dynamic data to back ground agent which is coming from web service?
One more thing is, there are two things like PeriodicTask & ResourceIntensiveTask. How can I use this to send a toast notification by using Background Agent?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this Tutorial From Nokia

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_create_simple_Background_Agent_in_Windows_Phone

and this from CodeProject

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/656654/Windows-Phone-Background-Agent-Part-Periodic-T